# Python - How can I simplify updating dictionary value to update it with substring of it

Tags: python, python-3.x

Instead of repeating or assigning it to a new variable how can I simplify this expression?

> ```py
>  dict['key'] = dict['key'][0:100]
> ```

In Dart one can do

```
  map.update('key', (v)=>  v.substring(0,100));
```

**UPDATE**

I see an update method in Python that I can be use as

```
dict.update({'key': new_value})
```

What I want is some kind of callback with a pointer to the original value of the dictionary.

**UPDATE 2**

Python

```
dict.update({'key': new_value})
```

What I want is

```
dict.update({'key' *self[0,100]})
```

where `*self` is original value instead of using `dict.get('key')`

Comment: Please, post [mre] and **elaborate what's exact problem you have with your current code**. Why do you find it "complex" or whatever? Are you trying to do for all key:value pairs or what?

Comment: "...some kind of callback with a pointer..." ? Please elaborate by way of example

Comment: See my example in Dart

Comment: Well, you can always define your own function and pass the dict and key and potentially start and stop indexes, but how it is simpler than assignment? And again, you will need to make an assignment inside that function.The Dart example (in my opinion) is no way more simple.

Comment: The code could be more succinct if the value is mutable (e.g., a list) by *del _dict['key'][100:]*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dict.update()`:

```py
product_dict['description'] = "So long decription I won't read"
product_dict.update({'description': product_dict['description'][3:15]})
```

Result:

```
>>> product_dict
{'description': 'long decript'}
```

I don't think it's necessary to look for another approach — this one is good as it is.
The one I suggested also uses repetition, but looks even a little bit tougher to read.

Comment: How is this simple than OP code? Yeah, I know this is opinion-based...

Comment: I don't think it's simple: >"but looks even a little bit tougher to read" :)
It would be better to use as is `my_dict['key'] = my_dict['key'][:100]`

Comment: If you don't think it's simple and even looks even a little bit tougher to read, why do you post as answer? Clearly there is lack of detail and OP need to elaborate what their problem with the current code is

Comment: In what way is this a simplification of the OP's `product_dict['description'] = product_dict['description'][0:100]`?

Comment: You are right. I just gave an example of another solution that may seem OP acceptable. At the same time, I mentioned that one should not look for a simpler writing of the given line. If you think the question should be left unanswered, it is better to pass it by.

Comment: @blhsing read the whole text in the answer, please. Also pay attention to comments.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the string value in your dictionary without an assignment as in Python [strings are inmutable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str). If you want to take the first 100 characters of your string you need to create a new string.

And if you don't want to write it on your own, you can use [`toolz.update_in`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.dicttoolz.update_in).
Inputs are the dictionary, the key in a list and the callback function.

```
my_dict = update_in(my_dict, ['key'], lambda val: val[0:100])
```

Notice you have to reassign the return value to `my_dict` as `update_in` will not modify your input dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dict comprehension maybe? I think it's quite concise and would allow updating every value in one line.

Using Python3

```
>>> d = {1: "abcdefghijk", 2 : "abdcefghijk", 3: "abcdefghijk"}
>>> d = {k:v[2:5] for (k,v) in d.items()}
>>> d
{1: 'cde', 2: 'dce', 3: 'cde'}
```